# In Elasticsearch how do I boost selected terms while still using a wildcard?

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I can't figure out from the documentation how to do a wildcard search across several terms but just boost/de-boost a few.

I have a JSON construct like:

```
{
  'indices_boost': {
    'football': 1.2,
    'horse-race': 1.1
  },
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'minimum_number_should_match': 2,
      'should': [
        {
          'wildcard': {
            'name': {
              'boost': 1.2,
              'value': 'polan*'
            }
          }
        },
        {
          'wildcard': {
            'nicknames': u
            'polan*'
          }
        },
        {
          'wildcard': {
            'horses': 'polan*'
          }
        },
        {
          'wildcard': {
            'jockeys': 'polan*'
          }
        },
        {
          'wildcard': {
            'parent': {
              'boost': 0.7,
              'value': 'polan*'
            }
          }
        },
        {
          'terms': {
            'minimum_match': 1,
            'state': [
              'upcoming',
              'live'
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  'size': 5
}
```

The intent is that a wildcard match on the `name` field should be boosted, while a wildcard match on the `parent` field is still relevant but shouldn't be put above results where `name` is matched.

This particular query doesn't return results even though it should (a query for `_all` with wildcard returns results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'boost':0.0 to eliminate impact of the matched term on the score.

If you have non-default analyzers specified for your fields, these fields might contain terms that are different from the _all field, which might explain why wildcards work for _all but fail for individual fields.

Comment: Not using any analysers. I'm also not sure what I would do with the `"boost":0.0` - I want things to score, but if it only matches the parent I want it to rank lower.

Comment: You query should work then. Can you post a reproduction of the issue?

Comment: I was actually being an idiot and was querying an old field - the schema had since changed. I'll accept your answer as the boost tip is helpful.

Comment: boost of 0 still makes a difference for me in the score on match vs no match

Comment: @BradWright exactly where did you put `boost=0.0` in the query presented above? Thanks!